# Error: assignment to expression with array type with number

Tags: arrays, c, sorting, struct, insertion-sort

I want to really know why did I get this error when working with numbers that stored in array? I saw similar error when people only working with string. This is the line that of code that get the error:

1. `55 |          data[j + 1].score1 = data[j].score1;`
2. `59 |          data[j + 1].score1 = key;`
3. `69 |          data[j + 1].score1 = data[j].score1;`
4. `73 |          data[j + 1].score1 = key;`

This is the code I'm working with:

```
struct input{
    float minimum, maximum;
    int many;
}input1;

struct input2{
    float score1[100];
    char name1[100];
};

void swapname(char *a, char *b){
    char z[1000];
    strcpy(z, a);
    strcpy(a, b);
    strcpy(b, z);
}

void insertionSort(int type, struct input2 data[100]) { 
    int step;

   if (type == 1){//desc
     int size = input1.many;
     for (step = 1; step < size; step++) { 
         float key = *data[step].score1; 
         int j = step - 1; 
  
         while (key > *data[j].score1 && j >= 0) { 
             data[j + 1].score1 = data[j].score1; 
         swapname(data[j+1].name1, data[j].name1);
             j = j - 1; 
         } 
         data[j + 1].score1 = key; 
     } 
   }
   else if (type == 2){//asc 
     int size = input1.many;
     for (step = 1; step < size; step++) { 
         float key = *data[step].score1; 
         int j = step - 1; 
  
         while (key < *data[j].score1 && j >= 0) { 
             data[j + 1].score1 = data[j].score1; 
         swapname(data[j+1].name1, data[j].name1);
         j = j - 1;
         } 
         data[j + 1].score1 = key; 
     } 
   }

}
```

Comment: `data[j + 1].score1` is a `float[100]` but `key` is a `float`.

Comment: And for `data[j + 1].score1 = data[j].score1;` : both are `float[100]` but you cannot assign arrays in C. You have to copy them element by element or use `memcpy`.

Comment: If you want to copy arrays you must do it for each element  of the array. score1 is an array not a variable self means that score1 stores the first memory location of the float array not float itself. But for example if you want to assign  a value to the first float member of array then you must do it like: data[x].score1[0] = 55.33; or if you want to compare 5th float member you must do it like: if (data.score1[4] > 100.00).

Comment: Could you please give me an example? @Jabberwocky